# Scala list search recursively

Tags: scala

I have a sample file(tab separated), i have to use linear recursion to search the tree list for a given state.

Input File:

```
    Quercus acerifolia  mapleleaf oak   MN
    Quercus _acutidens      CA
    Quercus acutissima  sawtooth oak    AL,GA,LA,MD,MS,NC,PA,VA
    Quercus agrifolia   California live oak CA
    Quercus alba    white oak    AL,AR,CT,DC,DE,FL,GA,IA,IL,IN,KS,KY,LA
    Quercus ajdfensis   Ajo Mountain scrub oak ,MN

    First Column - Tree Name(Genus Species)
    Second Column - Common Tree name
    Third Column - State Name
```

Code using recursion:

```
    //declaring package
    package HW10

    //declaring object
    object TreesStub {

    //importing Source package for files import
      import scala.io.Source

      //assigning the file path to filename variable
      val fileName = "trees.tsv" //tab separated

      //defining Main function
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        //reading source file from a file which is tabe separated
        val treeList: List[String] = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toList

        //Creating mutable list to append element which found a match
        var stateList = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]:()

        //Checking the list if empty then print empty list else call the function
        if(treeList.isEmpty) println("Empty List")
        else searchTreesRecursively(state,treeList) //calling recurive func

        //Calling recursive function search trees using "state" name and each line of //file(as second parameter)    
       def searchTreesRecursively(state: String, trees: List[String]): Unit = {
  //matching the trees list 
        trees match {
            case Nil => println(stateList) //If empty print the entire list

            //taking each line and splitting the lines using and matching with the state //given    

            case x => x.map(x => (x.split("\t", -1))).filter(_.length > 2).map(x1=> if(x1(2).contains(state)) stateList+= x(0) 

            //calling function recursively for the rest of the elements of the list
            else searchTreesRecursively(state,x1->next)}//next //element of list

        }
      }

    }
```

Here i am trying to call the recursive function for each element of the list "x1" in case statement. I am not sure how to call the second element of the list throught recursion i used "searchTreesRecursively(state,x1->next)}"  but i am getting error as "Type Mismatch".

```
    I know we can use x::xs for iterating the list, but i am not sure how i can use it to fit in this logic. Please let me know.
```

Comment: `x1->next` is a lambda, not a `List[String]`. You need to use `x1.next` I guess. Or maybe even `trees.tail`? Where is `x1` defined?

Comment: I did the x1.next as well but didnt work. x1 is the item in the "map" function.Here is the code line:- map(x1=> {if(x1(2).contains(state)) stateList+= x(0) else searchTreesRecursively(state,x1.next)})}

Comment: `x1->next` is not a lambda its a tuple but there is no value for next, i assume you want to get the tail of the list with .tail but why are you mapping over the entire list every time?

Comment: Ah, the weird formatting made it hard to read. I though the `else` belonged to the `trees match` block.

Comment: Yes it's belong to the match. Here is the function code:-                   
 def searchTreesRecursively(state: String, trees: List[String]): Unit = {
      trees match {
              case Nil => println(stateList)
              case x => x.map(x => (x.split("\t", -1))).filter(_.length > 2).
               map(x1=> {if(x1(2).contains(state)) stateList+= x(0) else searchTreesRecursively(state,x1.next)})}

    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your pattern in this pattern matching,

So... a List in Scala can be thought to be something like,

```
list = elem1 :: elem2 :: elem3 :: Nil
```

or,

```
list = elem1 :: (elem2 :: (elem3 :: (Nil)))
```

or,

```
list = elem1 :: tail1
```

where,

```
tail1 = (elem2 :: (elem3 :: (Nil)))
```

So, if lets say you want to recursively do  `abcdef` on elements of this list,

```
def abcdef(list: List[String]): Unit = {
  case Nil => println("nil")
  case head :: tail => {
    println(head)
    abcdef(tail)
  }
}
```

Comment: I treid this:-   def searchTreesRecursively(state: String, trees: List[String]): Unit = {
      val list1 = trees.map(x => (x.split("\t", -1))).filter(_.length > 2).toList
      list1 match {
        case Nil => println(stateList)
        case x :: xs => {if(x(2) == state) stateList+= x(0) else xs.map( _ => searchTreesRecursively(state,_))}}}                                                 Still it's showing error as "Error:(53, 108) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$4) => searchTreesRecursively(state, x$4))  case x :: xs => {if(x(2) == state) stateList+= x(0) "